# How to record with sox?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-recording, text-to-speech, sox

I would like to record some text-to-speech. Right now I pipe the audio to play so that it can be played. The command that I use to play the tts is    `play -q -`

I have tried using audio-record and    `arecord -f cd -t raw | lame -x -r - out.mp3` which I found online but I only hear static. With the `rec` command, I can't hear anything.

I don't know what else to do or what to check since I'm not very experience with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to record audio, you can use this ppa although ppas are untrusted:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:osmoma/audio-recorder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```

This won't work on 15.10+. If you are using 15.10+ let me know and I'll post instructions on how to install on newer versions.

Here are the instructions for later versions (Ubuntu 15.X, 16.X, & 17.X):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audio-recorder/ppa
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall audio-recorder
```

[Click here for more info and for instructions on removing the old ppa if needed.](https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: @Zanna Thanks, I finally have this on my newer version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

To @mchid and others:
Audio-recorder for 15.10 has been released. There is a new PPA that belongs to the team.
Plase see:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2295381

Comment: I have updated my answer with the latest available ppa from the team.